# Dependency Injection in Angular 2 Creates Multiple Instances while using Inline Injector and Constructor Injection

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, dependency-injection

I'm working on a Ionic 2 TypeScript project.
During application startup I inject a service through the constructor.

```
@App({
    providers: [ MyService ]
})
export class MyApp {
   constructor( private instance1 : MyService ){}
}
```

And in another class i use

```
let injector = Injector.resolveAndCreate ( [ MyService ] );
let instance2 = injector .get( MyService  );
```

I get two different instance of variables instance1 and instance2.

Is there any possible way to make them as one instance by using the inline Injector and Constructor

Comment: The behavior is expected (see my answer). To be able to suggest a workaround I would need to know more about your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Singletons" are maintained per provider instance. If you create a new `Injector` (that's what `Injector.resolveAndCreate ( [ MyService ] );` does, then it also has it's own provider instances. Therefore the behavior is expected.

You can inject the `Injector` to your component and service and create a child injector which then could work as expected.

If you need an injector where you can't inject the Angular injector, there is a workaround explained in this comment (with Plunker) https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-153811572

Comment: Just add `injector:Injector` as constructor parameter. You can use it to request instances (I think it was `injector.get(SomeType)`) or to create child injectors. I'm only on the phone therefore not more details.